# file_get_contents empty spaces removal for Google image API

Tags: php, api

Currently i was facing a problem while developing a dictionary where i can show google image with meanings and it works fine.

The problem was the API was showing this warning message while submitting more than 1 words to the URL in PHP.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=Pakistani Flag)
```

In the above example the API works fine to find out picture for Pakistani but adding Flag creating problems to show the message given above.

Answer (score 3):

```
$encoded = urlencode('Pakistani Flag');
```

Answer (score 2):

We can reslove the problem by replacing the empty spaces with %20 in PHP, for example your words are stored in a varible $word

```
$word = "Pakistani Flag";
```

convert the words with

```
$word_con = str_replace(" ", "%20", $word);
```

Finally we have

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=$word_con
```

which works absolutely perfect!